# Why js .reduce() behaves differently when array.length==1?

Tags: javascript, reduce

Why JS .reduce() behavior differs when the reduced array has only 1 element?

```
//friends with 2 elements behave as expected
var friends = [ 
                  {a:1, books: ['Bible', 'Harry']},
                  {a:2, books: ['War', 'Romeo']},
              ] 
var allbooks = friends.reduce((prev, curr) => [prev.books, curr.books]) 
console.log(allbooks)  //as expected: [["Bible","Harry"],["War","Romeo"]]
```

However, if friends.length==1, it returns the whole object instead of just books prop:

```
var friends = [ {a:1, books: ['Bible', 'Harry']} ]
var allbooks = friends.reduce((prev, curr) => [prev.books, curr.books]) 
console.log(allbooks)  //result:  {"a":1,"books":["Bible","Harry"]}
```

Comment: Your reducer doesn't work. For a third book in the array, prev.books would be undefined (because prev is now an _array_). You should read what reduce actually does: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: Just use: `friends.map(o => o.books)` if `[["Bible","Harry"],["War","Romeo"]]` is the expected result

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the second argument to `reduce` which seeds the operation with a start value.

The behavior of `reduce` changes with and without this second argument. Without the second argument, it treats the first element as the seed.

> initialValue Optional
> A value to which previousValue is initialized the first time the callback is called. If initialValue is specified, that also causes currentValue to be initialized to the first value in the array. If initialValue is not specified, previousValue is initialized to the first value in the array, and currentValue is initialized to the second value in the array.

[`reduce` Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)